# Json Gson expected Begin Object but was string

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am using the following code to contain this Json

```
public class RequestsDTO
{
    @SerializedName ("requests")
    public Requests requestsContainer;

    public  class Requests 
    {
        @SerializedName ("request")
        public List<Request> requests;      
    }

    public class Request
    {

        @SerializedName ("amount")
        public Amount amount;

        @SerializedName ("id")
        public int requestId;

        @SerializedName ("status")
        public Status status;

        @SerializedName ("created")
        public String  created;
        @SerializedName ("start")
        public String start;

        @SerializedName ("notes")
        public Notes notes;

        @SerializedName ("type")
        public Type type;

        @SerializedName ("employee")
        public Employee employee;

        @SerializedName ("end")
        public String end;
    }

    public class Amount
    {

        @SerializedName ("content")
        public int time;
        @SerializedName ("unit")
        public String unit;
    }
    public  class Status
    {

        @SerializedName ("content")
        public String currentStatus;
        @SerializedName ("lastChanged")
        public String lastChangedDate;
        @SerializedName ("lastChangedByUserId")
        public int lastChangedByUserId;
    }
    public  class Notes
    {
        @SerializedName ("note")
        public List<Note> note;
    }
    public  class Note
    {
        @SerializedName ("content")
        public String content;
        @SerializedName ("from")
        public String from;
    }
    public  class Type
    {
        @SerializedName ("content")
        public String content;
        @SerializedName ("id")
        public int id;
    }
    public  class Employee
    {
        @SerializedName ("content")
        public String content;
        @SerializedName ("id")
        public int id;
    }
}
```

and the json:

```
 {"requests": {"request": [
     {
         "amount": {
             "content": 2,
             "unit": "hours"
         },
         "id": 246,
         "status": {
             "content": "superceded",
             "lastChanged": "2012-10-24",
             "lastChangedByUserId": 2270
         },
         "created": "2012-10-11",
         "start": "2012-10-20",
         "notes": {"note": [
             {
                 "content": "Having wisdom teeth removed.",
                 "from": "employee"
             },
             {
                 "content": "Get well soon",
                 "from": "manager"
             }
         ]},
         "type": {
             "content": "Vacation",
             "id": 4
         },
         "employee": {
             "content": "Michael Daniels",
             "id": 40350
         },
         "end": "2012-10-25"
     },
```

I am building my Gson like so:

```
public class Json {
    private static Gson gson;

    private static class MyNoteClassTypeAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<List<RequestsDTO.Note>> {
        public List<RequestsDTO.Note> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext ctx) {
            List<RequestsDTO.Note> vals = new ArrayList<RequestsDTO.Note>();
            if (json.isJsonArray()) {
                for (JsonElement e : json.getAsJsonArray()) {
                    vals.add((RequestsDTO.Note) ctx.deserialize(e, RequestsDTO.Note.class));
                }
            } else if (json.isJsonObject()) {
                vals.add((RequestsDTO.Note) ctx.deserialize(json,RequestsDTO.Note.class));
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected JSON type: " + json.getClass());
            }
            return vals;
        }
    }

    public static Gson getGson()
    {
        if (gson == null)
        {
            Type ListType = new TypeToken<List<RequestsDTO.Note>>() {}.getType();
            GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
            builder.registerTypeAdapter(DateTime.class, new DateTimeSerializer());
            builder.registerTypeAdapter(ListType, new MyNoteClassTypeAdapter());
            gson = builder.create();
        }
        return gson;
    }
}
```

the reason for this is because the list of "Note.class" can comeback as a list or as a single object.

And finally building it like this

```
Json.getGson().fromJson(response, RequestsDTO.class);
```

Something is going worng ehre and I cant figure out what. It has been troubling me for the past few hours.

I get this error

```
    11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1648)
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1662)
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3696)
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963): Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1932 column 20
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176)
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:795)
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:761)
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:710)
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:682)
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at com.mokinetworks.bamboohr.service.WebService.getTimeOffRequests(WebService.java:154)
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at com.mokinetworks.bamboohr.ViewRequestActivity.onCreate(ViewRequestActivity.java:29)
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1610)
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     ... 11 more
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1932 column 20
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.expect(JsonReader.java:339)
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:322)
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:165)
11-07 20:04:57.097: E/AndroidRuntime(6963):     ... 28 more
```

Does anyone have any idea what is going wrong?

the line 1932 in my json points here

```
 "created": "2012-10-20",
    "start": "2012-10-29",
    "notes": "",            <---------line 1932
    "type": {
        "content": "Vacation",
        "id": 4
    },
```

Comment: What's the full stack trace?

Comment: I have now included the full stack trace

Comment: Can you post the complete JSON please.

Comment: The complete Json is 2400 lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken there's some JSON parse error as mentioned in the error, at:

```
line 1932 column 20
```

What does your JSON look like at that line?

Comment: Ok so here is the issue, apparently notes are one of 3 things, an aray of notes, a single object of notes, or a "notes": "",

Answer (score -1):

Your RequestDTO contains the field notes that is an Object.

```
@SerializedName ("notes")
public Notes notes;
```

But the JSON gives you a string

```
"notes": "",
```

Hence the error.

The solution would be to change Notes to String.

```
@SerializedName ("notes")
public String notes;
```

Comment: This was solved a long time ago by writing a custom serializer. However a simpler solution would have been to have the service team rethink the incorrect way they were sending data. Unfortunately we could not get them to, hence the solution. The real issue stemmed from their bad architecture where "notes" was a empty String when there was no object (empty|null data), a JSONObject when having a single entity, and a JSONArray when having more than 1 entity. The service should have always returned an array, whether it was empty, containing a single object, or multiple objects.